# How to get single data from sqlite database in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

As I am new to android. I am developing little app based on stock management of single product. User can add/remove stock and can check current stock. I tried to code for getting single data from database, but not accurate. The stock is added/removed successfully into the database. But when I kill or restart the app, the last stock value what I need cannot find their.

This is my database file DataBaseHandler.java

```
package com.example.stockmanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    private SQLiteDatabase sql=null;
    private static String CREATE_TABLE="";

    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, Util.DATABASE_NAME, null, Util.DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +Util.STOCK_TABLE + "("
                +Util.USER_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                +Util.CURRENT_STOCK +" TEXT NOT NULL, "
                +Util.DATE +" TEXT NOT NULL, "
                +Util.TIME +" TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        Log.i("Authentication", ""+CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +Util.STOCK_TABLE);
    }

    public void insertDetails(Model m)
    {
        sql=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cn=new ContentValues();

        cn.put(Util.CURRENT_STOCK, m.getCurrentStock());
        cn.put(Util.DATE, m.getDate().toString());
        cn.put(Util.TIME, m.getTime().toString());
        long insertId=sql.insert(Util.STOCK_TABLE, null, cn);
        Log.i("new raw inserted", ""+insertId);
    }

    public List<Model> getAllDetails()
    {
        List<Model> show=new ArrayList<Model>(); 
        sql=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=null;
        String query="SELECT * FROM" +Util.STOCK_TABLE;
        cursor=sql.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Model m=new Model();
            m.setCurrentStock(cursor.getString(0));
            m.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
            m.setTime(cursor.getString(2));
            show.add(m);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        sql.close();
        return show;
    }


    public Model getLastStock(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Util.STOCK_TABLE, new String[] {Util.CURRENT_STOCK}, Util.USER_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Model m = new Model();
        m.setCurrentStock(cursor.getString(0));

        Log.i("Message of Current Stock", ""+m);
        return m;
    }

}
```

The method getLastStock() is coded to get the lastly entered stock value for the further operation.

This is my java file for add/remove the stock Add_Remove.java

```
package com.example.stockmanager;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Add_Remove extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button btn1,btn2;
    private EditText edt;
    private DataBaseHandler data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__remove);

        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add__remove, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String number=edt.getText().toString();
        int count1=Integer.parseInt(number);
        Model m=new Model();
        data=new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        String ss= m.getCurrentStock();
        Log.i("CURRENT_STOCK", ""+ss);
        int count2;

        //While Stock is Added
        if(v.equals(btn1))
        {


            Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();

            //Getting Date
            String CiDate = "" + ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" +
                (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +
                ci.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            //Getting Time
            String CiTime =ci.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" +
                ci.get(Calendar.MINUTE) +  ":" +
                ci.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            if(ss==null)
            {
                 count2=0; 
                 Log.i("Count1", ""+count1);
                    Log.i("Count2", ""+count2);

                    int add=count1+count2;
                    Log.i("ADDED VALUE:", ""+add);
                    String stock=String.valueOf(add);

                    m.setCurrentStock(stock);
                    m.setDate(CiDate);
                    m.setTime(CiTime);  

                    data.insertDetails(m);

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                count2=Integer.parseInt(ss);
                Log.i("Count1", ""+count1);
                Log.i("Count2", ""+count2);

                int add=count1+count2;
                Log.i("ADDED VALUE:", ""+add);
                String stock=String.valueOf(add);


                m.setCurrentStock(stock);
                m.setDate(CiDate);
                m.setTime(CiTime);  

                data.insertDetails(m);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

        }


        //While Stock is Deducted

        if(v.equals(btn2))
        {
            Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();

            //Getting Date
            String CiDate = "" + ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" +
                (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +
                ci.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            //Getting Time
            String CiTime =ci.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" +
                ci.get(Calendar.MINUTE) +  ":" +
                ci.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            if(ss==null)
            {
                 count2=0; 
                 Log.i("Count1", ""+count1);
                    Log.i("Count2", ""+count2);

                    int add=count1+count2;
                    Log.i("ADDED VALUE:", ""+add);
                    String stock=String.valueOf(add);

                    m.setCurrentStock(stock);
                    m.setDate(CiDate);
                    m.setTime(CiTime);  

                    data.insertDetails(m);

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                count2=Integer.parseInt(ss);
                Log.i("Count1", ""+count1);
                Log.i("Count2", ""+count2);

                int add=count1-count2;
                Log.i("ADDED VALUE:", ""+add);
                String stock=String.valueOf(add);


                m.setCurrentStock(stock);
                m.setDate(CiDate);
                m.setTime(CiTime);  

                data.insertDetails(m);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Deducted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }       }
    }

}
```

Help me with proper database code to get the last stock value from database. So that I can further add or remove the stock.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
select max(USER_ID), CURRENT_STOCK from STOCK_TABLE group by CURRENT_STOCK
```

Comment: Just I need the last value entered into the table. But whenever I kill or restart the app it initialize the count2 value as 0.

Comment: yes. you did not store that value. you can get the last one with the max()

Comment: can you please write the code. so that I can get proper idea. @eduyayo   Thanks in advance

Comment: I´ve done it already... maybe you should replace your constants with whatever the names I´ve put in there. Maybe, if u just need the max ID you can return the max(user_ID) without the grouping.

Comment: Or, if you just need the amount of inserted rows, you can `select a count(1) from stock_table`

Comment: what value did it return?? By the way, you´ve got an autonumeric you don´t need to count to have a next id

Comment: I am getting null value from it. @eduyayo

Comment: from MY query, I mean

Comment: so... liteal copy paste did return null?... notice I will downvote the question if u answer is wrong

Comment: sir give me your email address I will send you the project. @eduyayo